# Bookdown gitbook bibliography will not split references by chapter

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown, bibliography

I'm adding references to a Bookdown document (gitbook style) and I would like them to to appear at the end of the chapter they're cited in.  No matter what I try, the rendered version of the book keeps placing them all at the end of the final chapter.  Does anyone have any suggestions for how to fix this?  Did I somehow screw up my `split_bib = TRUE` argument? Here are the configuration settings I have:

**_output.yml:**

```yaml
bookdown::gitbook:
  css: style.css
  split_by: chapter
  split_bib: true
  config:
    sharing:
      facebook: false
      twitter: false
    toc:
      collapse: section
      scroll_highlight: true
      before: |
        <li><a href="./">Book Title</a></li>
      after: |
        <li><a href="https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown" target="blank">Published with bookdown</a></li>
bookdown::pdf_book:
  toc_appendix: true
  toc_depth: 3
  fig_width: 6.5
  documentclass: book
  classoption: oneside
  df_print: kable
```

**_bookdown.yml:**

```yaml
book_filename: "file-name"
language:
  ui:
    chapter_name: ""
delete_merged_file: true
rmd_files: 
  - index.Rmd
  # A bunch of other rmd files; this part is working
```

**Beginning of index.Rmd:**

```yaml
title: "title"
author: "author"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
description: "Description"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
output: 
  bookdown::pdf_book
  bookdown::gitbook
bibliography: [book.bib, packages.bib]
csl: copeia.csl
link-citations: yes
```

Comment: Bookdown projects are quite complicated, so it's really hard to put enough in a question for someone to run it.  Can you post a link to either your full project or a dummy project with the same structure that we can try?